# Display recursive struct in c

Tags: c, recursion, struct

```
    idx x, z ;
    for (x = 0 ; x < k ; ++x) { 
        if (mots[x].mot) { 
            printf("%s :", mots[x].mot) ;
            //Below not working properly how to write all my refs ?
            // printf("%i ", mots[x].refs -> cdr ->ref);
            // while (mots[x].refs -> cdr) printf("%i ", mots[x].refs -> ref); 
            printf("\n") ;
```

How to iterate properly on my struct in order to display each refs of mots[x] ?

I hope the problem is clear enough, thanks in advance

Comment: Of which type is mots[]? If its a struct please post the typedef. Is it a recursive struct or do you just want to iterate over the flat mots[] array?

Comment: We know nothing about the types `str`, `idx`, what `split_chars` contains, how `False` and `True` are defined, what `cons` and `indice` are, etc. Imagine the *only* exposure you have to your problem is what you've posted here, and *nothing else*. Welcome to our world.

Comment: I want to iterate on the recursive struct , if I write (while iterating) mots[x].refs -> ref I'll get a result but I also want the results that are in the embedded struct

Comment: I added the full program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (mots[x].mot) { 
    printf("%s :", mots[x].mot) ;
    struct node *node = mots[x].refs;
    while (node) {
         printf("%i ", node->ref);
         node = node->cdr;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```